# ColdFusion function/logic to provide n number of white spaces between strings

Tags: coldfusion

I have to write a text file using ColdFusion. In that text file I need 'n' number of white spaces between strings.

For example:

```
'This<44 spaces>is<60 spaces>a<120 spaces>sampleText.'
```

So for this I'm using the `ljustify()` function in the places of white spaces, like

```
'This'&#ljustify(" ",44)#&'is'&#ljustify(" ",60)#&'a'&#ljustify(" ",120)#&'sampleText.'
```

I'm thinking that this will not be a coding standard. So, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Are the number of spaces dependent on the size of the words? i.e. do you always need column 1 to be 50 characters, regardless of whether the word is 'This' or 'The'? If you don't, then repeatString() can be used too

Comment: @barnyr umm okay, but that also similar to ljustify() right?

Comment: If ljustify gives you the desired results, I don't see any reason to not use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like what you want is `RepeatString()`.

> Creates a string that contains a specified number of repetitions of the specified string

Takes two parameters:

1. A string (or a variable that contains one)
2. Number of repeats

`"This" & RepeatString(" ",44) & "is" & RepeatString(" ",60) & "a" & RepeatString(" ",120) & "sampleText."`

Of course, you don't need to use a space. You can use `RepeatString` to repeat just about anything.

LJustify() is for "padding" a string with characters out to a set number of spaces.

Example:

```
[#LJustify("These",10)#]<br>
[#LJustify("are",10)#]<br>
[#LJustify("variable",10)#]<br>
[#LJustify("size",10)#]
```

would give you output like

```
[These     ]
[are       ]
[variable  ]
[size      ]
```

This is especially useful for creating fixed-length strings.